# How to do a pop up, over the Google Map's SDK

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, swift3, google-maps-markers

Im using the Google Map's SDK and want the user to fill out some information about a marker.

So the user presses on the map to place a marker, I want a small pop up to come over the map and ask the user to input some text about the location. Should that pop up be its own view controller or should it be a UIView and subview the mapController?

Comment: You can simply present `AlertController` with the `textField`.

Comment: I think I want to add some buttons as well. I really want to make it look custom

Comment: Use a UIView and add as subview of mapview.